# Using DropDownListFor in combination with ValidationMessageFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am currently trying to combine the Html Helper functions `DropDownListFor` and `ValidationMessageFor`. I am using asp.Net MVC 5 and have generated a model. My goal is to have an HTML select-box, which is generated by the function `DropDownListFor`. This should be linked to my model. It is assumed that the client enters something into the field in the frontend in the select-box. If the client doesn't enter anything and clicks on the submit button of my form, the `ValidationMessageFor` function should be used to display the error text I entered in the model. Of course the form shouldn't be valid and the client shouldn't be allowed to continue as long as nothing is selected in the select-box. That's the theory.

As already mentioned, I have created a model. It looks like this:

```
public class ExampleModel
{        
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Test-Error-Text")]
    public string salutation { get; set; }
}
```

I set the values in the select-box in the controller as follows:

```
var collection = new ListItemCollection();
collection.Add(new ListItem("Mr"));
collection.Add(new ListItem("Mrs"));
collection.Add(new ListItem("unknown"));
collection.Add(new ListItem("company"));

var selList = new SelectList(collection, "Salutation");
ViewBag.Salutation = selList;
```

Then I call the functions in the view as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model=> Model.salutation, ViewBag.Salutation as SelectList, "", new { @class="adrInput form-control"})            
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model=>Model.salutation)
```

As this is currently, I get the following exception when submitting:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'salutation'.'
```

I have almost never worked with these Html Helper functions. Something is wrong here. I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. I have to return the model to the view after submitting the form, if the form is not valid. Furthermore I have to initialize the SelectList for the ViewBag again. Somehow the values get lost in ViewBag.Salutation after validation.

Answer (score 0):

In your VIEW, would you happen to have something like this?

```
@model IEnumerable<Sample1.Models.ExampleModel>
```

If so, remove "IEnumerable", and just do:

```
@model Sample1.Models.ExampleModel
```

Comment: No. In my view I integrate the model as follows: `@model Samlple1.Models.ExampleModel`